# How to control fast clicks on treeview control?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, treeview

I am using GMAP library and I am painting different markers on it. I am using a treeview control where I put the names of the markers and when I check or uncheck the name, the marker associated appears or disappears.

I tried to do this using checklistbox and listview control too, and the treeview control is what I need because I need to have categories of markers, and some subitems inside of that categories. This is the code:

Here i fill the treeview with the elements I need on it:

```
Private Sub addelementsToTreeview()
    frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(StringResources.ControlCenterTree)
    frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(StringResources.FOTree)
    frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(StringResources.ArtilleryTree)

    For Each value In foOverlay.Markers
        frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes.Add(value.ToolTipText)
    Next
    For Each value In artilleryOverlay.Markers
        frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes(2).Nodes.Add(value.ToolTipText)
    Next
    frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.CheckBoxes = True
    frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes(0).Checked = True
    frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes(1).Checked = True
    frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes(2).Checked = True
    For i As Integer = 0 To frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes(1).GetNodeCount(False) - 1
        frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes(i).Checked = True
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes(2).GetNodeCount(False) - 1
        frmConfiguration_.TreeView1.Nodes(2).Nodes(i).Checked = True
    Next
End Sub
```

I use a handler to control the itemCheck event, placed in the Form_Load:

```
AddHandler TreeView1.AfterCheck, AddressOf treeview1_ItemCheck
```

*I also have tried using `TreeView1.BeforeCheck` but has the same effect.

And here is when I show or hide the items I am checking or unchecking:

```
Private Sub treeview1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs)
    Dim counter As Integer
    'Dim a = sender.treenode.parent
    If sender.nodes.count > 0 Then
        If e.Node.Text = StringResources.ControlCenterTree And e.Node.Checked = True Then
            padre.controlCenterOverlay.IsVisibile = True
        ElseIf e.Node.Text = StringResources.ControlCenterTree And e.Node.Checked = False Then
            padre.controlCenterOverlay.IsVisibile = False
        ElseIf e.Node.Text = StringResources.FOTree And e.Node.Checked = True Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To TreeView1.Nodes(1).GetNodeCount(False) - 1
                counter = i
                TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes(counter).Checked = True
                Dim marker As GMarkerGoogle = padre.foOverlay.Markers.FirstOrDefault(Function(o) o.ToolTipText = TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes(counter).Text)
                marker.IsVisible = True
            Next
        ElseIf e.Node.Text = StringResources.FOTree And e.Node.Checked = False Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To TreeView1.Nodes(1).GetNodeCount(False) - 1
                counter = i
                TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes(counter).Checked = False
                Dim marker As GMarkerGoogle = padre.foOverlay.Markers.FirstOrDefault(Function(o) o.ToolTipText = TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes(counter).Text)
                marker.IsVisible = False
            Next
        ElseIf e.Node.Text = StringResources.ArtilleryTree And e.Node.Checked = True Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To TreeView1.Nodes(2).GetNodeCount(False) - 1
                counter = i
                TreeView1.Nodes(2).Nodes(counter).Checked = True
                Dim marker As GMarkerGoogle = padre.artilleryOverlay.Markers.FirstOrDefault(Function(o) o.ToolTipText = TreeView1.Nodes(2).Nodes(counter).Text)
                marker.IsVisible = True
            Next
        ElseIf e.Node.Text = StringResources.ArtilleryTree And e.Node.Checked = False Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To TreeView1.Nodes(2).GetNodeCount(False) - 1
                counter = i
                TreeView1.Nodes(2).Nodes(counter).Checked = False
                Dim marker As GMarkerGoogle = padre.foOverlay.Markers.FirstOrDefault(Function(o) o.ToolTipText = TreeView1.Nodes(2).Nodes(counter).Text)
                marker.IsVisible = False
            Next
        Else
            Dim marker As GMarkerGoogle = padre.foOverlay.Markers.FirstOrDefault(Function(o) o.ToolTipText = e.Node.Text)
            If marker Is Nothing Then
                marker = padre.artilleryOverlay.Markers.FirstOrDefault(Function(o) o.ToolTipText = e.Node.Text)
            End If
            If marker IsNot Nothing And e.Node.Checked = True Then
                marker.IsVisible = True
            ElseIf marker IsNot Nothing And e.Node.Checked = False Then
                marker.IsVisible = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

One problem and one question about this. First the problem:

- When I check and uncheck fast on an item, is like the code executes slower than the clicks, and the control does not respond very well. I have to click slower again to recover the behavior I have programmed, and I don't know how to control this. If I do double click on a checkbox of the treeview, I need to see how the marker appears and disappears at the same speed I am checking and unchecking. Someone know ho to do this??

Now the other question:
- About the code, I am using `if..elseif..else` structure. I also have tried using `Select Case` structure, but this last one is not value for me because I have two conditions to ask, and in `Select Case` I can only put one. I mean, this is not possible:

```
select case e.node.text, e.node.checked
```

at the beginning of the structure. So this structure is not valid for this.

Some can give me some advice to do it in a more efficient way? Because I can not imagine how to do it better.

thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3408088/17034

Comment: Perfect!! That's exactly what I needed. I used this solution and works perfectly! Do you know why they don't fix this bug? Thanks a lot!